# Kotlin and Android Jetpack support in Android platform apps

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I want to create an application which use some of the framework APIs. I have set the `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
In order to avoid reflection, I have imported the framework.jar
The apk is platform signed and I successfully installed the app.

However when I launch the app it crashes. The exception is

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. It is unable to find the MainActivity.
>       Another exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity".

I wish to know whether the `framework.jar` supports Kotlin and Android Jetpack libraries.

Gradle dependency:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'
implementation files('libs/framework.jar')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add those two lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Try to add / change below line to your `app/build.gradle`

```
// implementation "androidx.core:core:1.0.2" 
// use below kotlin dependency
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2"
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the following properties
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
kotlin.code.style=official

Comment: how is your gradle file like?

Comment: Please check the dependencies above